# Pycharm - keep highlighted word as argument

Tags: python, pycharm

Does Pycharm have the feature to keep highlighted word as the argument? To better ilustrate what I mean let me show you an example:

```
some_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl']
for i in some_list:
    # Do something
```

Now what I would like to do is to highlight `some_list` in `for` loop and type `enumerate` where desired output would be `enumerate(some_list)`. This is a feature that I found really handy while using LaTeX.

Hope I was clear enough.

Comment: not sure what version you are using and if it is available there but it does have this thing called "postfix templates" if I am not mistaken. For example you can try it with `print`. Type `some_list` then `.print` and hit tab. It gets reformatted to `print(some_list)`. Maybe you can configure those to include `enumerate` too.

Comment: I'm using Pycharm community edition 2017.1.5

Comment: its newer than mine, should be there.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/postfix-completion.html

Comment: It does not seem to be configurable.. Sorry.

Comment: This is not exactly what i was looking for. It is a handy trick. Unfortunately it's mostly useful when I write code from scratch and not while correcting it (like the example I gave in question).

Comment: @Ev.Kounis No problem. Thanks for searching the possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [surround](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/surrounding-blocks-of-code-with-language-constructs.html) feature:

1. Select *some_list* in IDE
2. Click on `Code -> Surround With` in menu (<kbd>⌥⌘T</kbd> shortcut on Mac)
3. From drop-down menu choose `1. (expr.)`
4. Profit!

Alternatively, you can use [Surround live templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-code-constructs-using-surround-templates.html) feature of Live Templates:

1. Open settings
2. Go to `Editor > Live Templates`
3. In python group create new template with such content `enumerate($SELECTION$)`
4. Save it with some name, e.g. **tenum**
5. At the bottom of setting window click on `Define` link and select `Python` (otherwise you will get *No surround templates defined in this context*)
6. Select *some_list* in the IDE
7. Press <kbd>⌥⌘J</kbd>
8. From the menu select your newly defined template **tenum**
9. Profit!

Comment: `Ctrl+Alt+T` on Windows. This also isn't exactly what I'm looking for. The problem is that I need to press `Ctrl+Alt+T`, select what I want to do deselect highlighted and type in desired function.

Comment: this is much better. Hope they implement it for any function.

Comment: What do you mean `for any function`? For example, you can use predefined live template `itere` to get your iteration with enumerator. And nothing stops you from defining your own for anything else. I think live templates are very powerful feature.

Comment: I mean to use highlighted text to use as argument for any function.

Comment: because as I have implemented now thanks to you I can only do this to enumerate.